# search not working - Fatal error - magento 2

Tags: php, magento, search, magento2

My website is in Magento ver. 2.2.3

early my search functionality was working properly ..but no idea suddenly from last week i am getting below error message ...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNext() on
>   null in
>   /home/website/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor/Interceptor.php:1465
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/website/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor/Interceptor.php(13):
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor\Interceptor->___init()
>    #1 /home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper),
>   Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver),
>   Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data), Array) #2
>   /home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Catalog...',
>   in
>   /home/website/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor/Interceptor.php
>   on line 1465

below is above path interceptor.php code line 1465:

> ```
> /**
>  * {@inheritdoc}
>  */
> public function ___init()
> {
>     $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, '___init');
>     if (!$pluginInfo) {
>         return parent::___init();
>     } else {
>         return $this->___callPlugins('___init', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * {@inheritdoc}
>  */
> public function ___callParent($method, array $arguments)
> {
>     $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, '___callParent');
>     if (!$pluginInfo) {
>         return parent::___callParent($method, $arguments);
>     } else {
>         return $this->___callPlugins('___callParent', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
>     }
> }
> ```

**i tried :**

```
rm -rf generated
rm -rf var/cache
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

and then

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

but still getting above error message .... as new to magento2 - no idea what going wrong ...

thanks

Comment: Can any one help me

Comment: Are you using opcache, apcu or similar? If that's the case, could be just that you need to restart your apache or php-fpm services...